# Error when run ClickToBuild.bat file

Tags: orchardcms-1.9

I  downloaded the orchard galley server from codeplex repository in this link:
https://galleryserver.codeplex.com

when I want to run ClickToBuild.bat file according of the Readme.txt file for 
build and run all of the tests in both projects, show this error:

[image]

any one can help me?!
thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the project has been discontinued. So you probably will not have support from the author. second, its from 2011.

Looking at your errors, it might seem you are missing assets being referenced. If you look closely to the project tree and read the Error you will see how there are Nuget packages being used. those might need updating for your project to build.

If it is an old nuget version, depending on your VS version might have problems but it salvageable. Just need to make sure all your packages are updated before building.

If you look at UpdateNuGet.bat you will be able to see how it tries to do something in the folder where the compiler tries to find the asset.

Good luck